# Selector cancels UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a small UIImageView that I am panning within a view using a UIPanGestureRecognizer. I am simultaneously running a selector which essentially acts as a timer by decrementing an int by 1 every second, updating a UILabel to reflect the change, and calling itself again until the int reaches 0. The problem is that every time the updateTime method is called it cancels the pan gesture and the UIImageView returns to its original location within the main view.

I tried detaching the updateTime method in a new thread but it didn't recursively call itself after being called first time. I also tried using UIButtons instead of UIImageViews and calling the - (void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event method to handle the buttons frame change but that did not fix the problem either. How can I keep the timer running while panning?

Here is the code for the UIPanGestureRecognizer:

```
- (IBAction)imagePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {    
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
```

And the timer:

```
- (void) updateTime {
if (!running) return;

timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", timeLeft];

timeLeft--;

if (timeLeft == 0) {
    running = false;
    timerLabel.text = @"";
    return;
}
[self performSelector:@selector(updateTime) withObject:self afterDelay:1];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Very odd. Not saying this will necessarily help, but have you tried using an `NSTimer` instead of using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`?